# Lengthy Install

Tags: system-installation, system

I am installing Linux Ubuntu 14.4 tonight and it has been installing for almost 3 hours.  The spinning wheel is going round and round and the page it is on shows some of the features in Ubuntu.  I did check the box install updates.  Is this normal time to install and should I just be patient. If it never get to the finished installing screen what should I do. Any help apprediated.

Comment: That certainly doesn't look normal, unless your internet connection is very slow. Right above the progress bar, there should be a triangle along with some text about the status. Click on the triangle to see more information about what it's doing right now.

Comment: I have looked for the triangle you refer to and see none.  The progress bar is there and just sitting and I do have icons on the top of the page like it would be home page but no triangle up there either.  Any suggestions.

Comment: If it takes much time or it doesn't respond stop the installation and try reinstalling without "install updates" & network connection. You will get updates while you are using Ubuntu after installation.

Comment: Thanks again for responding....I just did a shut down on the computer and started an install again from the beginning without checking the update box.  It seems to be installing as I see it pulling in language packs etc which it did not do before.  Thanks again and I will let you know the outcome

Answer (score 0):

If you asked it to install updates then it will have to download them first. Usually with a normal DSL connection of around 3-4Mbps this will take 30 minutes and another 30 for the installation. If you have a better connection then you might want to restart the installation because it probably froze. It is always a good idea to check the checksum of the downloaded iso to make sure that it is not corrupted before starting the installation. I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding.Since I chose to install Ubuntu over Windows 7 how do I restart the install.  Do I shut off the computer and boot again from the USB drive as I did for the beginning.  My internet connection is cable and quite fast so I am not sure if it is frozen or not.  I did read some comments about others taking a long time.  One person suggested 6 hours.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi Bill, my installation took roughly 30 minutes including downloading and installing all the updates on a moderate laptop. Since you are doing a clean install, meaning that you do not keep any data then you can simply reboot/restart your computer. I would choose to press the restart button rather than pull the plug and then start over.